# Two database with the same name - how to dump?

Tags: postgresql

I have two database with the same name after a manipulation error (I think).
When I try to dump the one owned by `bussiere` it always dumps the empty one owned by `postgres`.

```
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding  | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 dbbiotech | bussiere | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
 ddbiotech | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |           |         |       | bussiere=CTc/postgres
 postgres  | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
 template0 | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. The name is different: `dbbiotech` is not `ddbiotech`.

Looks like a misunderstanding. It wouldn't be possible to have the same name twice in the same DB cluster to begin with. Postgres does not allow it.

Comment: This solution helped me! I was trying to create a database from a command line script, and running into a very strange issue where it would be created in the script, and then appear not to exist when I would try to connect. Running `psql -U postgres -l ` allowed me to see the full output and cause of my issue, which is that the script was adding a \r newline character to the database name.

Comment: Is there any possibility to manage two or more databases with the same name?
like the first one is `dbbiotech`, and the second one is also `dbbiotech`.

Comment: @Adwin: Yes, in distinct db clusters. Else, no. Wouldn't make sense anyway.